# Why do we need FileInputStream in = null; line before try block?

Tags: java, fileinputstream

This code from oracle i/o tutorial:

```
public class CopyBytes {
public static void main(String[] args) throws IOException {

    FileInputStream in = null;
    FileOutputStream out = null;

    try {
        in = new FileInputStream("xanadu.txt");
        out = new FileOutputStream("outagain.txt");
        int c;
```

Why these lines

```
FileInputStream in = null;
FileOutputStream out = null;
```

not included to try block in this way (without `= null`)?

```
 FileInputStream in = new FileInputStream("xanadu.txt");
 FileOutputStream out = new FileOutputStream("outagain.txt");
```

Comment: Because of the code in the `finally` block, that you didn't show. Anyway, it's old style and should generally be replaced with [try-with-resources](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/essential/exceptions/tryResourceClose.html) (Java 7+).

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You need to declare `in` and `out` outside `try {...}` because you need to close these resources in the `finally {...}` block.

```
FileInputStream in = null;
FileOutputStream out = null;

try {
  in = new FileInputStream("xanadu.txt");
  out = new FileOutputStream("outagain.txt");
  int c;
  ....
} catch(Exception e) {

} finally {
   try {
     if(in != null) {       
       in.close();
     }
     if(out != null) {
       out.close();
     }
   catch(Exception e) {...}
}
```

If you declare them inside the scope of `try {...}` the compiler will complain that they could not be resolved.

If you do:

```
try {
  FileInputStream in = new FileInputStream("xanadu.txt");
  FileOutputStream out = new FileOutputStream("outagain.txt");
  int c;
  ....
} catch(Exception e) {

} finally {
   try {
     if(in != null) { //in could not be resolved error by compiler       
       in.close();
     }
     if(out != null) { //out could not be resolved...
       out.close();
     }
   catch(Exception e) {...}
}
```

Comment: Missing the `if (in != null)` and `if (out != null)` parts.

Answer (score 1):

If you declare and initializes the streams inside try block , in finally statement if you want to try to close the streams, the compiler doesn't know what are the values of **in** and **out** in order to close the streams.

```
FileInputStream in = null;
FileOutputStream out = null;

try {
   in = new FileInputStream("xanadu.txt");
   out = new FileOutputStream("outagain.txt");

  } catch(Exception e) {
     ----
  } finally {
     if(in!=null) {       
         in.close();
     }
     if(out!= null) {
       out.close();
     }
  }
```

Answer (score 0):

Because Inputstream is a heavy resource.
You have opened a FileInputStream and now while using it some exception occurs.
Then that stream will remain opened, wastage of resource.

So you initialize it with null before try block so that you can close it in finally block i.e. correct way to clean up resources.

```
FileInputStream in=null
    try{
       }catch(IOException ioexcep){
    }
    finally {
    in.close;
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

If you are using Java 7 or better, you can use try-with-resources, which will handle the close for you.

```
 try(
      FileInputStream in = new FileInputStream("xanadu.txt");
      FileOutputStream out = new FileOutputStream("outagain.txt");
  ) {
    .... do stuff
  } catch (Exception e) {
    ... deal with the exception
  };
```

This is because FileInputStream implements java.lang.AutoCloseable, so it will close() when the try block completes or an exception is thrown.